# Rails String Split

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Looking to split a data string (paramaters) into an array but have some specific criteria for this to occur on.  The string that I have looks like the following:

```
cyr_ad_id\tproject_number\tname\tremote_reference\tsample_size\tad_length\tsample_description\tmedia_type\tnotes\r\n13342a\t13342\tMore Dad_BC\t2897855894001\t150\t:30\t50% Customers\r\n50% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast\r\n13342c\t13342\tDRTV - Hogs\t2897815438001\t150\t:60\t100% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast\r\n13342d\t13342\tMake Way For More\t2897815439001\t150\t:30\t50% Customers\r\n50% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast\r\n
```

and I would like to have the following result:

```
["cyr_ad_id\tproject_number\tname\tremote_reference\tsample_size\tad_length\tsample_description\tmedia_type\tnotes", "13342a\t13342\tMore Dad_BC\t2897855894001\t150\t:30\t50% Customers\r\n50% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast", "13342c\t13342\tDRTV - Hogs\t2897815438001\t150\t:60\t100% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast", "13342d\t13342\tMake Way For More\t2897815439001\t150\t:30\t50% Customers\r\n50% Non-customers\tFilm\tBroadcast"]
```

What I feel like I need to do is something similar to splitting the string by "\r\n" after the 8th occurrence of "\t".  The 8th occurrence is something that I'd like to have passed into a split statement by a variable.

There are potential "\r\n" occurrences that I do not want to split this string by, hence why the nth or 8th occurrence of "\t" is critical in this example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this fit your need?

```
def ssplit str, n
  r = Regexp.new "([^\t]*?\t){#{n}}(.*?\r\n)"
  matched = []

  while s = str.slice!(r) do
    matched << s.strip
  end

  matched
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Just plugged that function into my app and after doing some brief testing it seems to be working just like I wanted! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`your_string.gsub("\r\n", "\t").gsub("\n", '').split("\t").each_slice(8).to_a`

Replace all `\r\n` with `\t`, then kill any left over `\n`. Split on the `\t`s.  Now you have an array of your items.

You could also probably use regex, which I can't seem to get to work.  `.split(/\\r|\\t|\\n/)`

`.each_slice(8).to_a` takes 8 items at a time and builds them back up, so you have an array for each of the groups.

you could also do `.in_groups_of(8)` instead of `.each_slice`.  no need for `.to_a` then, either.

```
[["cyr_ad_id", "project_number", "name", "remote_reference", "sample_size", "ad_length", "sample_description", "media_type"], ["notes", "13342a", "13342", "More Dad_BC", "2897855894001", "150", ":30", "50% Customers"], ["50% Non-customers", "Film", "Broadcast", "13342c", "13342", "DRTV - Hogs", "2897815438001", "150"], [":60", "100% Non-customers", "Film", "Broadcast", "13342d", "13342", "Make Way For More", "2897815439001"], ["150", ":30", "50% Customers", "50% Non-customers", "Film", "Broadcast"]]
```

That seems more usable?